# Error while make install xnee

Tags: software-installation, make, makefile

I did the `./configure` and `make` with root permission but I can't `make install`.
output:

```
Making install in libxnee
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee'
Making install in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee/src'
Making install in test
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee/test'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee/test'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libtestcb.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libtestcb.lai /usr/local/lib/libtestcb.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libtestcb.a /usr/local/lib/libtestcb.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libtestcb.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libtestcb.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee/test'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee/test'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/libxnee'
Making install in cnee
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee'
Making install in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee/src'
make  install-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee/src'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c cnee '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c cnee /usr/local/bin/cnee
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 cnee.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee/src'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/cnee'
Making install in gnee
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/gnee'
Making install in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/gnee/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../        -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-main.Tpo -c -o gnee-main.o `test -f 'main.c' || echo './'`main.c
main.c:35:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:475: recipe for target 'gnee-main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [gnee-main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/gnee/src'
Makefile:379: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/xnee-3.19/gnee'
Makefile:430: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You have just stripped the important parts of the compile log.  Could you add few more lines before "compilation terminated"?

Comment: It appears that your system doesn't have a gtk development package. Normally the `./configure` script would detect that and refuse to create the corresponding Makefiles, however it seems that in this case it is slipping through and allowing the build to fail later (possibly because it tries to use the deprecated `gtk-config` instead of `pkg-config`). Make sure the `libgtk2.0-dev` is installed and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Xnee can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnee cnee
```

GNU Xnee is a suite of programs that can record, replay and distribute user actions under the X11 environment. Think of it as a robot that can imitate the job you just did.

gnee: X event recorder/replayer - GUI flavor
cnee: X event recorder/replayer - command-line flavor

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the issue with configuration file setup so try with the below,

1) First check the source file,

```
tar xvf xnee-3.02.tar
```

2) Second check the Xnee directory,

```
cd xnee-3.02
```

After doing so please try with clean all and then try with installing again,

```
make clean all

make install
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: make clean all also failed...

Answer (score 0):

You can install **xnee** without difficult compilations by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxnee0
```

It is in the Official Ubuntu Repository.